# Anova between two models?Output R

Tags: r, anova, interpretation

I have to compare two models.
The first one is complete,with all predictors;the second one has only one predictor.
If i call the command anova(firstmodel,secondmodel), i get a Fisher test with very high p-value, then should i deduce that predictors are significant?

Comment: The answer you were given sounds perfectly correct. However, I was wondering if when you said "very high p-value" you really meant a very small (i.e. very significant) p-value?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a restricted model $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1$ and a full model $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3$, and store the fits in `m_restricted` and `m_full` respectively. When you execute `anova(m_restricted,m_full)` in R, the null hypothesis for your F-test is that $\beta_2=\beta_3=0$.

With a large p-value, you fail to reject the null hypothesis, so it actually looks like your predictors are not significant.